# Are all three of these sentences equally fine?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, word-order, sentence-patterns, correlative-comparatives

Are these all the same?

1. The more we earn, the less careful we become about money.
2. The more we earn, we become less careful about money.
3. The more we earn, the less careful we are about money.

I am confused about the sentence structures used here. I feel the first one makes sense though.

I hope someone can help me understand the rule behind this!

Comment: These are correlative comparison constructions, where the comparative phrase should be in front position, as in 1. and 2, thus 3. is ungrammatical.

Comment: Your #2 is *completely* "non-idiomatic", but the other 2 aren't so hot either, even though at least they both include the ***the more ... the less*** juxtaposition. The problem is you've switched from a ***verb*** with "more" to an ***adjective*** with "less", which rather messes up the "parallelism". Better would be to have a verb on both sides of the "equation", as in *The **more** we **earn**, the **less** we **care** about money.*

Comment: There's nothing at all wrong with 1. and 3. They are both grammatical and idiomatic.

Comment: Syntactically, when the whole subordinate clause is fronted, the comparative phrase in the head clause should also be fronted, as in 1. and 3. But in 2. it's not fronted, hence the loss of grammaticality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, FumbleFingers wrote:

> Your #2 is *completely* "non-idiomatic", but the other 2 aren't so hot either, even though at least they both include the ***the more ... the less*** juxtaposition. The problem is you've switched from a ***verb*** with "more" to an ***adjective*** with "less", which rather messes up the "parallelism". Better would be to have a verb on both sides of the "equation", as in *The **more** we **earn**, the **less** we **care** about money.*

Comment: Point taken! I should have answered rather than commenting. Whatever - at least I now get to upvote that *specific* point that the parallelism of ***the more X ... the less Y*** works better when ***X*** and ***Y*** are structurally / syntactically "equivalent". So ***more [verb] ... less [verb]*** is "better" than ***more [verb]*** ***... less [adjective]***

Comment: (Dang! Somebody *downvoted* it! :)

Comment: There are many examples, many of which sound idiomatic to my ear, of 'The older I get, the more/less I V' which are structurally unbalanced (adj v adv). But I agree this switch is more severe. I think I'm with you on 'not so hot'.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no rule except that the well established locution "the more … the less" is unchangeable and that all its parts must be preserved. Moreover the order of the elements in the construction is unique and can't be changed. According to this the first sentence and the third are correct.

*Examples*

- *The more* we learn, *the less* difficult it becomes to learn.
- <s>*The more* we learn, it becomes *the less difficult* to learn.</s>
- *The more* knowledge, *the less* difficulty in acquiring knowledge.

Note: Don't make too much of that "earn/learn" coincidence; I noticed it only as I was through with this answer.